# LoadString(AFX_IDP_PARSE_INT) fails in an mfc exe (not in a dll)

Tags: c++, mfc

`AFX_IDP_PARSE_INT` is the id for a standard MFC error message (it's defined in afxres.h), but in my project it fails to load, meaning that `LoadString` returns `FALSE`, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`, and CString stays empty.

This happens even when I try loading it at the beginning of InitInstanse:

```
BOOL CMyLegacyProject::InitInstance()
{
    CString string;
    if (!string.LoadString(AFX_IDP_PARSE_INT))
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed."));
}
```

This same code works on a new project, however - same linking of MFC (I link to it statically), same WINVER, I've tried making it as similar as my old project, but I can't reproduce the error on a newly started project.

Comment: Probably means you have an error somewhere else in your code. I would try systematically removing code from your old project, until the error goes away. When it goes away the last piece of code you removed is probably the code with the error. I would start with the code you were last working on when this error showed up.

Comment: Can you check `GetLastError` to see if it returns something that might be related?

Comment: It returns ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: @john I already put this code at the beginning of InitInstance, so it's executed before any other code, the exception being the constructors of any static or global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your resources are not building correctly. Make sure your .rc file includes all the AFX resources as well. First I'd try building a brand new project from scratch, test loading the string in that, and then have a look to see what the default .rc file looks like.

It should be including a file called 'afxres.rc', ie your RC should have something like this in it:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE 9, 1
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32
#include "res\MyRes.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources
#include "afxres.rc"         // Standard components
#include "afxprint.rc"       // printing/print preview resources
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I wasn't including "afxres.rc". When I added it to my rc file the string was now loading. I remember that I had tweaked the rc includes at one time to add some additional .rc2 files, and I must have removed it then without realizing. The strange thing is that I had a TEXTINCLUDE section that had a line with "#include ""afxres.rc"", but it probably didn't have an effect.