# MFC LoadString fails when attempting to load a string from afxres.rc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When my program attempts to generate an AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL error for the user, it fails to load the string that is stored in the afxres.rc file.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862139/loadstringafx-idp-parse-int-fails-in-an-mfc-exe-not-in-a-dll) already, however it was solved because the reference to afxres.rc was accidentally deleted from the program.rc file.  That is not the case for me.  My program.rc file includes the exact code listed in the answer to include the afxres.rc file.

In debug mode, it breaks on the ASSERT below.

```
int AFXAPI AfxMessageBox(UINT nIDPrompt, UINT nType, UINT nIDHelp)
{
 CString string;
 if (!string.LoadString(nIDPrompt))
 {
  TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: failed to load message box prompt string 0x%04x.\n", nIDPrompt);
  ASSERT(FALSE);
 }
 if (nIDHelp == (UINT)-1)
 nIDHelp = nIDPrompt;
 return AfxMessageBox(string, nType, nIDHelp);
}
```

When I am actually running the application via the .exe, it simply generates an empty warning box since the AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL string is not loaded; this goes for any string in the afxres.rc.

What could cause the application to not load the string from the afxres.rc?

Comment: Have you stepped into LoadString () to check if it is trying to load the string from the correct resource file?  Are you maybe changing the active resource handle?

Comment: Have you tried opening the binary resources for the exe in VS, and seeing if the AFX string resources have indeed been embedded correctly?

Comment: @rrirower I did step into the LoadString call multiple times.  I have researched but am still unsure of how to determine which resource file is being accessed.  It has been my concern from the beginnning that afxres.rc is not being looked at.  I did confirm that if I copy the AFX_IDP_PARSE_REAL definition into the string table of my program's resource file, there is no problem with the LoadString() call.  But I was not sure if that meant it was the only resource file checked or if it was one of many.

Comment: @user1793036 I have opened the binary resources, and everything appeared to be correct.

Comment: Trace LoadString () down into AfxFindStringResourceHandle ().  At the line where it calls AfxGetResourceHandle (), note the value of hInst.  Then, go to the menu item Debug/Windows/Modules.  Look for the handle you just collected in the Modules window.  It should point to the module that you expect to contain the string.  If it does not, there's a problem.

Comment: @rrirower Thanks for the further direction!  I had been keeping track of the hInst value but did not know about the Modules window to use for tracking.  It is still using the address for the program's resource file.  So it looks like I have more digging to determine why it is not getting the handle to afrxres.rc file.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know that it is not enough to include the afxres.rc file normally, the way you include header files into cpp/h files. You actually need to include it twice. If you create a brand new MFC project and check the code of an rc file (using "View Code" option) you would notice that there is a normal include:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"
```

and there is a `TEXTINCLUDE` section inside the rc file:

```
2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END
```

You need to make sure you do the same thing in your project. Alternatively, you can use a "Resource Includes" wizard that is available via right click on the Resource View that allows editing the both sections via the dialog box:

[image: VC Resource Includes wizard]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my resource file does have the
    include  and the
    2 TEXTINCLUDE  code sections that you mention.